# What is an analog multiplexer? Do we have a 2:1 analog mux?

Tags: multiplexer

I have two analog signals with frequencies up to 8kHz. I need to select one of the signals using a digital logic select. How can I do this? I need the most reliable IC as our system demands the highest reliability.

Comment: What's the voltage swing?  Do you need DC coupling or AC coupling?  What sort of source and load impedances are we talking about here?

Comment: Analog muxing/switching devices are available as COTS devices.  Quick search of the internet shows a variety of parts, some up in the GHz range of bandwidth.

Comment: The signals are coming from a DC/DC converter output.It gives a 3.3 V output to  power a micro-controller.

Comment: Since you are apparently trying to switch a power supply, you need to tell us how much current will be drawn, and how much voltage drop is allowed across the multiplexer. Also, how fast does the switching process need to be?

Comment: around 40mAmps current will be drawn and very less voltage drop is allowed .. may be around 100mV

Comment: Please edit your question to include these requirements. Don't make potential answerers hunt for them in the comments.

Comment: I am still confused on one point. You refer to these as analog signals, but now you say they are power supply outputs. Are you injecting a low-amplitude signal on the power supply Voltage? Is cost a concern for this project? This can be done fairly easily and cheaply with an inverter and two discrete PMOS transistors.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a SPDT analog switch for this.

The [Fairchild FSA5157](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/FS/FSA5157.pdf) is a single-supply SPDT switch with a range of 0 to +V, where the supply voltage (V) can be from 1.8v to 3.3v.  The maximum on resistance is 0.7 Ω.  It is rated for a continuous switched current  of 350 mA.

[image]

The FSA5157 is available [from Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/FSA5157P6X/FSA5157P6XFSCT-ND/3478176) for $0.78 in single quantities

Comment: The signals are coming from a DC/DC converter output.It gives a +3.3 V output to  power a micro-controller

Comment: @student I updated my answer to include a single supply switch.  I left the dual supply in for reference.

Comment: @student I just saw the updates to your requirements.  The previous analog switches I had chosen were only rated for 10 mA.  This one can carry 350 mA.  With a current of 40 mA, and an on resistance of 0.7 Ω, the voltage drop will be in the order of 30 mV.